# Is double checked locking my cleanest option for ensuring task is called once?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a class that needs to do some processing of its private state (a ConcurrentDictionary) periodically. I am doing this via `Task.Factory.StartNew(doStuff)`. Because this task is modifying the collection, I want to ensure that doStuff is only executed one time when the condition becomes true. The work that it is doing is safe to ignore race conditions, but I don't want redundant tasks taking up resources and crowding out the synchronization if possible. Right now I have it controlled by double checked locking which works fine, but it is very verbose code to tack on the end of a method:

```
public void method()
{
    ...
    // do the method related stuff. Upon executing this method, the condition for
    // executing the task could become true, so it is appropriate to try to start it,
    // even though it is not directly related to the semantics of this method

    ...

    // now see if the task should be run
    if (clock.Now > timestamp.Plus(interval) && periodicTask == null)
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            if (periodicTask == null) 
                periodicTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(this.DoStuff);
        }
    }
}
private void DoStuff()
{      
    doActualProcessing();

    //signal that task is complete
    timestamp = clock.Now;
    periodicTask = null;
}
```

This set up will work to keep DoStuff from being called extra times, but it seems too verbose and a little dirty. Ideally, I would like to encapsulate this single-call logic so I can do something like this:

```
public void method()
{

    // do the method related stuff.
    ...

    // now see if the task should be run
    startTaskExactlyOnce(DoStuff);
}
```

The only option I have seen is to perhaps use `Lazy<T>` to accomplish this, but it doesn't seem appropriate here because:
1. I'm not initializing an object, I'm running a task
2. the task will be run periodically, a single time each period
3. I just need to start the task, so there would be no translation for using `Lazy<t>.Value` to cause the execution

Comment: Quick note: If you keep your present code, add a `Thread.MemoryBarrier` to the end of your `DoStuff` method. Otherwise, the `null` assignment might never be seen by the thread performing the check.

Comment: There was similar question answered several days ago:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603275/task-startorrestartwhenpossible/17603418

Comment: @Douglas: Even so, it's still racey without locking on `lockObject` when assigning to `periodicTask`.

Comment: ...and another barrier before the check, of course.

Comment: @spender: What you're saying applies to double-checked locking in general, but not to this case in particular, since the OP is not accessing any of the `Task`'s state from outside the lock.

Comment: What is the advantage of double-checked locking over single-checked locking? Double-checked locking introduces a low-lock path which can lead to race conditions in some memory models if you are not careful, so what compelling benefit are you obtaining by choosing the more dangerous mechanism?

Comment: In particular, how are you guaranteeing that the memory barriers necessary to ensure up-to-date reads of `periodicTask` are happening on the low-lock path?

Comment: @Douglas, can you expand on why Thread.MemoryBarrier is needed? In my case minor race conditions will be fine as long as the method is eventually called. I.e. if the reads are not immediately up to date it is safe to skip the task, as long as the the value is eventually read correctly.

Comment: @Eric The double check is to reduce chance of needing the lock, but it may be a case premature optimization.

Comment: @mao47: What is the value of `interval`? Unless it's on the order of milliseconds (or lower), I'd agree with Lippert and say it's premature optimization.

Comment: @Douglas interval can be at least on the order of minutes to hours. I introduced the double check when I realized that new threads coming into method() could potentially create a lot of tasks since the timestamp isn't updated until the task is complete. I may rework my condition to cut down on some of these and only use a single lock.

Comment: @mao47: Locks cost a few dozen nanoseconds if they are uncontended. This code seems to be doing all kinds of stuff; checking clocks and making comparisons and building tasks. Is it really the case that you can't afford a few dozen extra nanoseconds?  Conversely, if it is the case that the lock is being contended frequently, then surely the right thing to concentrate on is reducing contention directly, rather than going with a low-lock solution to reduce contention.

Comment: @Eric: Good point, I am convinced. I think I was thinking about DCL in the wrong way when I added it. I am moving back to a single check to create the task.

Comment: I stand corrected by @spender; my barrier suggestions would still leave the code prone to race hazards, since the compiler might reorder the null assignment to occur before the writes of `doActualProcessing`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would punt on the whole double-checked locking thing. I do not think it is going to buy you anything substantial for the risk premium you would pay. With that said your *specific* implementation is *probably* going to work okay. But, this is mostly accidental. Read on.

First, the write to `periodicTask` in `DoStuff` will get published immediately because 1) writes on x86 hardware have volatile semantics already and 2) an implicit memory barrier is generated for you at special synchronization points, namely the ending of a `Task` in this case, so even in weaker memory model environments the write-side of things is *probably* okay.

Second, the read of `periodicTask` in `method` will *probably* sneak past any optimizations because `clock.Now` (assuming it works like `DateTime.Now`) will *probably* generate an acquire-fence barrier, at the least, in its attempt to extract the current time from the system.

Notice how I kept using the word "probably"? There were several assumptions I made when drawing the above conclusions. It could be that I am dead wrong. Though, I can say with some confidence that my assumptions are most likely to be true. The point is why take the risk. Even if I am right this code could easily break when the next programmer gets in there are starts switching things around because he did not understand what your intentions were.

Let us get to back to the reason for the double-check locking pattern to begin with. As I said it is not really worth it. How often would you expect `method` to run when `periodicTask` is not `null`? That scenario would have to significantly outnumber all others (by...I do not know...maybe 100,000-to-1 or something) before you achieve any meaningful gain. The cost of a `lock` is really small so whatever tricks you play must have a really big bang-for-the-buck to make the effort worthwhile. I just do not see that happening in your scenario.

Answer (score 2):

You could avoid a lot of the nastier (and difficult to verify) logic by using [`Lazy<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx) in combination with [`Interlocked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.Interlocked.aspx).

```
Lazy<Task> periodicTaskLazy;

void RunDoStuffWithoutConcurrency()
{
    Lazy<Task> periodicTaskLazyLocal = 
         new Lazy<Task>(() => Task.Factory.StartNew(this.DoStuff));
    Interlocked.CompareExchange<Lazy<Task>>(
        ref periodicTaskLazy,
        periodicTaskLazyLocal,
        null);
    Task actualTask = periodicTaskLazy.Value;
}

void DoStuff()
{
    //....
    Interlocked.Exchange(ref periodicTaskLazy,null);
}
```

Although I suspect that [TPL Dataflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603.aspx) might be a better option for this sort of Task arbitration.

Answer (score 0):

if you want only one thread is modifying the dictionary, why do you use concurrent implementation? to me it seems like you just need timer. or you could schedule next run at the end of the processing method.

Comment: I am not familiar with Timer, but I think it could be used here. The difference would be that Timer forces the task to be called even if method() is not called (if method is never called the task doesn't actually need to run). I don't want to do this concurrently because this is a package that will be used in web application and I do not want to block a request while this task executes.

Comment: you could check that with a simple boolean flag. modifying dictionary doesnt ever block accessing it. and since only one thread modifies the dictionary (others just read it) you would normally not want to use concurrent version. its only used if there is a possibility more then one thread "modifying" it.